# Close previous popover by clicking on next

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

There are many popover on my page and I want to close the previous open popover by clicking on next popover.

It works! but when I click again on previous popover I have to click twice!

I, also, want popover to be closed by clicking outside.

```
$('.triggerOverlay').popover({ 
html : true,
content: function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var cont = $this.data('toggle');
        return $('#'+cont).html();
}});
```

The following code for closing all popover except the current

```
$('.triggerOverlay').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.triggerOverlay').not(this).popover('hide');
});
```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/yasirhaleem/43qfkjtb/

Comment: Try creating a jsfiddle for your question

Comment: @Tomanow fiddle added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Add the `click` event listener to the document, and always hide your popovers.
If the event target is one of your anchor tags with a popover then toggle it. Also added `trigger` property to the popover options set to `manual`.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('.triggerOverlay').popover({ 
    html : true,
    content: function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var cont = $this.data('toggle');
      return $('#'+cont).html();
    },
    trigger: 'manual'
  });


  $(document).on('click', function (e) {
    // always hide them all.
    $('.triggerOverlay').popover('hide');
    // if e.target has a popover toggle it.
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('triggerOverlay')) {
      $(e.target).popover('toggle');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.customoverlay{display:none;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="user-profile-overlay" class="triggerOverlay">button</a><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="user-profile-overlay" class="customoverlay">content goes here</div>
<a href="#" data-toggle="user-profile-overlay1" class="triggerOverlay">button</a><br><br><br><br>
<div id="user-profile-overlay1" class="customoverlay">second content goes here</div>
<a href="#" data-toggle="user-profile-overlay2" class="triggerOverlay">button</a><br><br><br>
<div id="user-profile-overlay2" class="customoverlay">third content goes here</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works!! but if i click within popover it disappers, also if i use google material icon inside anchor tag popover does't work can you please help to solve this issue

Comment: moved the triggeroverlay class to google icon and it works :) clicking within popover is also solved.